# Convert Set<Enums> to Set<String>

Tags: java, string, enums, set

I need to convert set of enums to set of strings, how it is possible?

```java
public enum Example {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

Set<Example> setOfExamples;
Set<String> setOfExamplesString;

setOfExamples.add(Example.A);
setOfExamples.add(Example.B);
setOfExamples.add(Example.A);
setOfExamples.add(Example.C);
```

Now I want to save (convert) the `setOfExamples` to `setOfExamplesString`.

Comment: Exactly what do you expect to have in `setOfExamplesString`? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: btw, there is no point adding `Example.A` to the set twice. It's a set. It doesn't care about duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd stream the set of enums, map them to strings, and collect them to a set:

```java
Set<String> setOfExamplesString = 
    setOfExamples.stream().map(Example::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**EDIT:**
To address the question in the comment, the same thing can be done with a straight-forward loop in Java versions before 8, although IMHO it won't be as elegant:

```java
Set<String> setOfExamplesString = new HashSet<>()
for (Example e : setOfExample) {
    setOfExampleString.add(e.name());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but It is not a universal solution. I would need it to work in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need the Set of Enum later in your program or not. But, if at all the intention is to get the Set of String using these Enum, then I believe adding the element to the Set of String itself in the first place is probably a better option to do.

we will simply use the name method on Enum which gives us the String representation. The code Snippet would be following

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
public enum Example {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<String> setOfExamplesString = new HashSet<>();

    setOfExamplesString.add(Example.A.name());
    setOfExamplesString.add(Example.B.name());
    setOfExamplesString.add(Example.C.name());
    System.out.println(setOfExamplesString);

}
}
```

Hope this helps.